# (Python noob) A string of numbers is getting split into digits when adding it to a list

Tags: python, string, list, integer, digits

I'm trying to find the even in a list of odds or the odd in a list of evens. This is what I've got:

```
def even_odd_finder(numbers):
    numlist = numbers.split()
    evens = []
    odds = []
    for m in numlist:
        n = int(m)
        if n % 2 != 0:
            odds += str(n)
        else:
            evens += str(n)
    if len(evens) > len(odds):
        this_one = odds[0]
        odd_ind = numlist.index(this_one)
        return "Entry  " + str(odd_ind + 1) + " is odd."
    else: 
        no_this_one = evens[0]
        even_ind = numlist.index(no_this_one)
        return "Entry " + str(even_ind + 1) + " is even."
```

This works fine and dandy when I pass it a string of single digit integers.

```
print(even_odd_finder("1 2 5 7 9"))
print(even_odd_finder("2 4 6 7 8")) 
print(even_odd_finder("88 96 66 51 14 88 2 92 18 72 18 88 20 30 4 82 90 100 24 46"))
```

At the third one though, I noticed I'm getting a `ValueError: '5' is not in list` because the when the double digit numbers are getting put into the evens and odds lists, they're getting broken down further into their digits. `"8"` and `"8"` are getting put into evens, rather than `"88"`, so the first entry in the odds list, `odds[0]`, is `'5'` rather than `'51'`. I can't figure out why.

Comment: `odds.append(str(n))`, `+=` is for concatenating lists (similar to `extend()` not `append()`). `odds += [str(n)]` would work but is way more effort. `odds += str(n)` doesn't break because a string is considered a sequence, but `odds += n` would throw an error.

Comment: In addition, I think there will be error when there is no even/odd number in input string such as ```"11 33 55"``` because ```odds[0]``` or ```evens[0]``` don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of numbers, it's better to handle it as a list of numbers.

- lists are useful, use them

  - *no need to build a string of numbers via `stringofnumber += str(n)`*
  - *change `evens` and `odds` to lists*

I refactored your code a bit:

```
def even_odd_finder(numbers):
    numlist = [int(n) for n in numbers.split()]
    evens = []
    odds = []
    for n in numlist:
        if n % 2 != 0:
            odds.append(n)
        else:
            evens.append(n)

    if len(evens) > len(odds):
        this_one = odds[0]
        odd_index = numlist.index(this_one)
        return f"Entry {odd_index + 1} is odd."
    else: 
        no_this_one = evens[0]
        even_index = numlist.index(no_this_one)

def even_odd_finder(numbers):
    numlist = [int(n) for n in numbers.split()]
    evens = []
    odds = []
    for n in numlist:
        if n % 2 != 0:
            odds.append(n)
        else:
            evens.append(n)

    if len(evens) > len(odds):
        this_one = odds[0]
        odd_index = numlist.index(this_one)
        return f"Entry {odd_index + 1} is odd."
    else: 
        no_this_one = evens[0]
        even_index = numlist.index(no_this_one)
        return f"Entry {even_index + 1} is even."
        return f"Entry {even_index + 1} is even."
```

> NOTE: you will still get an error if `events` or `odds` are empty

In terms of code usability, I would *clean* your input before handling by your function.  In other words covert your string of numbers to a list *before* giving it to your function.  This provides better [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) for better code.